# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Buenas noches estoy cargando contenido a través de una respuesta de AJAX:

```
$('#info_casa').html('<tr>\
   <td class="font14"><strong>Adultos </strong></td>\
   <td class="td_flex">\
     <div class="number-input posicion_cantidad_carrito">\
     <button class="cantidadAdultos" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector("input[type=number]").stepDown()" ></button>\
     <input class="qtHuespedes backCantidad" min="0" name="qtHuespedes" value="0" type="number">\
     <button class="cantidadAdultos masAdultos plus" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector("input[type=number]").stepUp()"></button>\
    </div>\
   </td>\
   </tr>');
```

Pero creo que esta parte no funciona `onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector("input[type=number]").stepDown()"` creo que es por tema de comillas pero no logro hacer que funcione.

Comment: ensaya poniendo un backslash \ antes de cada comilla doble del parametro que le pasas a querySelector

Comment: Aparte de la sugerencia de @Pipe, también puedes probar con comillas simples: `onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown()"`

Comment: Buenos días, al final a funcionado de con las dos cosas, poniendo las comillas simples y añadiendo el backslash antes de casa comilla. Gracias a los dos

Answer (score 0):

podrías cambiar las comillas dobles del selector por las simples: `this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]')`

Aunque lo más conveniente sería asignar el evento con jQuery una vez que creas el contenido de `info_casa` con otro selector.